# MySQL count without grouping

Tags: mysql, count

I am running the following query to understand to get users' first attempt to answer a question listed next to their second attempt.

```
SELECT 
  s.id AS attempt_id_first, m.id AS attempt_id_second, s.user_id 
FROM 
  attempt s 
  INNER JOIN attempt m on s.user_id = m.user_id  
WHERE 
  s.id<m.id
```

I end up with this:

```
attempt_first   attempt_second  user_id
7   17  1
9   10  2
9   15  2
10  15  2
4   6   9
24  25  15
29  34  19
29  36  19
34  36  19
```

I would like to have a new column that counts the number of attempts by users so that:

```
7   17  1  1
9   10  2  3
9   15  2  3
10  15  2  3
4   6   9  1
24  25  15  1
29  34  19  3
29  36  19  3
34  36  19  3
```

I am sure this is trivial, but I cannot get it to work. Help anyone?

Comment: I think you need to find a way to format that better.  Nevermind - it got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is it: Just display the results, and throw in an extra count subquery:

```
select
  userid,
  id,
  (select
    count('x') 
  from 
    attempt x 
  where 
    x.userid = a.userid) as attempcount
from
  attempt a
```

If you like to keep the first and second attempt in separate columns, you can of course embed the subselect in your original query.

It seems wrong, though. Firstly, you need to have at least two attemps, otherwise none will show. You can solve that by changing `inner join` to `left join` and move the condition in the `where` clause to that join. Secondly, the 'second attempt' is not the second attempt per say. Actually, for each of the attempts you get all next attempts. Look at the example of user 2. You accidentally get three rows (where there are three attemps), but you get attempt 9 and 10, as well as attempt 9 and 15 as well as 10 and 15. 9, 15 is incorrect, since 15 isn't the attempt that followed 9. The more attempts a user has, the more of these false results you will get.

Comment: Alas, this doesn't answer the question.  Your query is quite different from the OP's query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is an issue with querying first and second item, since the way OP does it, you get *any* next item. Yet, in the example data he gives this same issue occurs. I tried to address this issue, and gave the possibility that OP might not want/need to query the first and second attempt at all (why would you, if you also return the second attempt in a separate row).

Comment: @GordonLinoff But rather than acknowledging OP's error and my thought on the matter, you just post a query, which doesn't return the list OP asked for (so it's also wrong), but also doesn't show any explanation or motivation. And then you are posting a negative comment to my answer (again!) to draw more attention to yours?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one attempt listed next to the next one, with the count, I would suggest:

```
SELECT s.user_id, s.id AS attempt_id_first, 
       (select s2.id
        from attempt s2
        where s2.user_id = s.user_id and
              s2.id > s.id
        order by s2.id
        limit 1
       ) as attempt_id_second,
       (select count(*)
        from attempt s3
        where s3.user_id = s.user_id
       ) as totalAttempts
FROM attempt s ;
```

This only lists each attempt once with the next one.  The count is included as the last column.